# Blurring effect also applying on Navbar and the Navbar Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

In this code, although I applied,

```
nav.classList.toggle("blur-0");
list.classList.toggle("blur-none");
```

but the Navbar and the Navbar Menu get blurred.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./output.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="flex bg-green-600 w-screen h-[40px] max-md:h-[65px] sticky top-0">
        <div class="max-md:ml-[15px] font-bold w-[5%] h-[75%] p-[2px] m-[7px] flex justify-center items-center">Logo</div>
        <div class="font-bold p-[2px] h-[75%] m-[7px] w-[35%] flex justify-center items-center max-sm:w-[20%] max-md:mx-auto">Title</div>
        <div class="bg-green-600 flex md:space-x-10 max-md:space-y-5 justify-end items-center w-[60%] max-md:w-screen max-md:flex-col max-md:absolute max-md:top-[-170%] duration-500" id="list">
            <div class="font-bold">Services</div>
            <div class="font-bold">About</div>
            <div class="font-bold">Contact Us</div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden max-md:flex justify-center items-center mr-[2%] w-[6%] h-[75%] p-[6px] m-[7px] cursor-pointer rounded-full hover:bg-green-700 duration-500 max-sm:w-[11%]">
            <i class="fa fa-bars" id="icon"></i>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="h-[2000px] flex justify-center items-start bg-black w-screen">Helo</div>
    <div class="w-screen h-[50px] bg-cyan-500 sticky top-0">hwlooo</div>
    <div class="h-[2000px]">Helo</div>
    <script>
        const x = document.getElementById("icon");
        const list = document.getElementById("list");
        const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
        x.onclick = (e)=>{
            e.target.classList.value = (e.target.classList.value == "fa fa-bars") ? "fa fa-close" : "fa fa-bars";
            list.classList.toggle("max-md:top-[99%]");
            nav.classList.toggle("blur-0");
            list.classList.toggle("blur-none");
            document.body.classList.toggle("blur");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried with some custom CSS, like I added two classes and applied the backdrop filter with 0 and blur(10px) and toggled those classes in body and navbar and navbar menu also, but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "undo" a blur inside an element that has been blurred.

Instead, you could consider wrapping the elements that want blurred in another element, so that you can blur *that* element, leaving the `<nav>` **outside** of said element:

```js
const x = document.getElementById("icon");
const list = document.getElementById("list");
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
x.onclick = (e)=>{
    e.target.classList.value = (e.target.classList.value == "fa fa-bars") ? "fa fa-close" : "fa fa-bars";
    list.classList.toggle("max-md:top-[99%]");
    document.querySelector('main').classList.toggle("blur");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="flex bg-green-600 w-screen h-[40px] max-md:h-[65px] sticky top-0 z-10">
        <div class="max-md:ml-[15px] font-bold w-[5%] h-[75%] p-[2px] m-[7px] flex justify-center items-center">Logo</div>
        <div class="font-bold p-[2px] h-[75%] m-[7px] w-[35%] flex justify-center items-center max-sm:w-[20%] max-md:mx-auto">Title</div>
        <div class="bg-green-600 flex md:space-x-10 max-md:space-y-5 justify-end items-center w-[60%] max-md:w-screen max-md:flex-col max-md:absolute max-md:top-[-170%] duration-500" id="list">
            <div class="font-bold">Services</div>
            <div class="font-bold">About</div>
            <div class="font-bold">Contact Us</div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden max-md:flex justify-center items-center mr-[2%] w-[6%] h-[75%] p-[6px] m-[7px] cursor-pointer rounded-full hover:bg-green-700 duration-500 max-sm:w-[11%]">
            <i class="fa fa-bars" id="icon"></i>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <main>
      <div class="h-[2000px] flex justify-center items-start bg-black w-screen">Helo</div>
      <div class="w-screen h-[50px] bg-cyan-500 sticky top-0">hwlooo</div>
      <div class="h-[2000px]">Helo</div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```